# Is porn considered harmful sexual.activity?

Tags: harmful, sexual, activity

I don't have a sex life because I don't have a partner and I don't wish to engage in casual sex so I use porn to quench the biological urge to orgasm. I can't see that's it's harmful because nobody is being forced into it. The actors are all paid well and claim to enjoy it etc. The only harm I can see is that it's so accessible these days on smart devices and so children may access it but I believe that this is the parents responsibility to not allow unsupervised use of devices etc. Views?

Comment: >The actors are all paid well and claim to enjoy it etc. ... Porn industry reeling after five deaths in only three months

FIVE porn stars have died in the last 12 weeks alone as a crisis rocks the sex industry, with workers revealing just how badly they are treated.   https://www.news.com.au/lifestyle/real-life/news-life/porn-industry-reeling-after-five-deaths-in-only-three-months/news-story/e779587b387f0ad2b3ae71ec45f0c631

Comment: If you do your research, even rich famous pornstars going back in history for many decades, often have tragedies. Drug addiction, being sex trafficed as kids,  suicide, etc. Those riches and fame have a heavy price.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is wrong with it but not ethically in my opinion. Also it is wrong only in the pragmatic sense and not in the moral sense.

Probably I shouldn't be the one preaching, but I have come to see the bad effects myself so... Yes it is bad because every orgasm come with a possibility to get attached to it, to the pleasure. For most of us, this possibility actually materializes into attachment. This creates the mind to wander on this pleasure (automatically) which further brings up urges/craving for orgasm. so hopefully you can see that it's a spiral which can easily get out of hand, and you may get addicted to it.

Over a long time, with consistent use, it can basically destroy your will and your mental strength. you won't be able to concentrate half as long as you are able to now, you will feel lazy and sleepy more often and your IQ will drop substantially.

As per buddhism, I am not entirely sure because I'm not that well read. But I'm sure someone else can point to instances where the Buddha insists on celibacy or points to the negative effects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its harmful,
On moral ground its not hidden that porn industry most of the time forces and do not pay enough.you are indirectly fueling that cruelty.

Porn is not suggested even for Sex or masturbation. Because you are using mental power to indulge into it. Its too much for brain.

Ideally you should masturbate without porn. if possible (or later) you can masturbate even without fantasy or imagination.  This will create very less burden to brain. and body knows well what to do. Ejaculating is work of body and not mind. This way you are actually free from it.

Later when you want to go for complete celibacy, its much easier, since you have disconnected mind from this bodily act.

Staying away from porm, soft  porn or engaging mind into fantasy etc is Big NO, even for married person. Even fantasizing about your legal partner is big NO.To that extent we must follow 3rd precept. that will help greatly in achieving Deep samadhi.

Answer (score 1):

> Is porn considered harmful sexual activity?

Although not strictly speaking forbidden for a householder, it does have its drawbacks namely being addicted as pointed out by the other answers. It is definitely not allowed in [the case of a monk](https://suttacentral.net/pli-tv-bu-vb-ss1/en/brahmali?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin) which is a good reference for what is wholesome or unwholesome behaviour.

One of the possible methods to overcome compulsive or impulsive behaviour (including addiction) is perhaps to focus on the unbearable part in our life. Sometimes, we allow ourselves to be addicted to sensual pleasures like porn, sex, alcohol, vaping, caffeine and so on because we are trying desperately to escape from something.

I know it is contradictory that we are forcing ourselves to face the very thing that our instinct is telling us to run away from. Perhaps, what you find hard to reconcile is the fact that you are alone and the ensuing loneliness that the mind associate this with. By associating being alone with negative emotions like loneliness, it creates a fertile ground for other negativities like depression, anxiety, stress and so on. But it does not have to be this way.

If we observe people in relationships, sometimes, we see them feeling lonely and unhappy. I have seen my fair share of abusive relationships as well. Emotional dependencies can be both a boon and a bane. Despite the hit and miss nature of relationships, people invested a huge amount of time, effort and resources in them. Personally, I have nothing against this but I realized that the healthier relationships tend to occur amongst people who are emotionally balanced and mature to begin with.

This meant they don’t need others to be dependent on them or vice-versa. To these people, being alone is not something that needs to be associated with loneliness or any negativities. Instead of focusing on the negative aspects of a situation (being alone, poor, ordinary, not street-smart and so on), we can focus on the positive aspects. The advantage of being alone? There is a lot of freedom. The benefit of being poor? We are hungry and willing to work hard. The pros of having only average or below average intelligence? We don’t have the cleverness to scheme and hurt others for our selfish greed.

Changing our views of what’s wrong in our lives takes time and initially plays a supporting role. The first step is still to create distance and time apart from our unskillful habits. When the mind is no longer compelled or impelled all the time, there is then some calm, normalcy and room for us to relook, rethink, revise and rebalance our perceptions and thinking of what is unbearable into something that just fine and OK.

Answer (score 0):

In another thread, you asked about pleasant sensations and jhāna.
I'm guessing you're young, so here's some important advice you won't get from suttas
if you're serious about jhāna.
(since monastics are already celibate by rule)
If you want to attain stable and higher jhānas,
celibacy and noble silence to the best of your ability are the feedstock and prerequiste to that.

The jhānas and other samādhi attainments are not just a mental transformation but a physical transformation as well.
Reproduction is one of the most energetically intensive operations a body can do.
You don't have enough energy to indulge in sexual activity, sensual pleasures,
and also attain higher jhānas.
It's as if you only have 1 million dollars to last your whole life,
and stable jhāna costs 600k$,
and going to the whore house, or having ethical sex with your girlfriend,
or watching porn costs 20k$ each pop.
Those 20k$ pops don't seem like much when you're young and still have close to a million dollars,
but if you don't heed this valuable advice and you're older it will be too late to change your mind.

If you follow 5 precepts and stay with moderate level of ethical sexual activity and sensual pleasures,
most likely that will put your jhāna ceiling at a mediocre first jhāna and low quality second jhāna.

If you watch a lot of porn and indulge in a lot of sexual activity and sensual pleasures like most lay people,
you're going to experience the typical problems they do.
Anxiety, depression, loss of memory, poor cognitive function,
poor immune system, head aches, body aches, irritability, etc.

Sexual urges are difficult when you're young.
Even highly attained spiritual beings find it difficult looking back, see Ajahn Chah's biography for example.
If I had things to do over and be young again, the way I would deal with urges is have intensive physical exercise as an outlet when urges are especially difficult.

If you jog for several miles for example, the energy in your body is going to circulate and when your mind is off of sex for a while, and the body tired from the exercise, then you'll have some temporary relief.

The main key though is to focus the mind on the downsides of sexual activity and sensual pleasure rather than on the subha nimitta (attractive and alluring elements of the opposite sex and sensual pleasures).

The key to long term success is once you truly see and understand the insatiability, unreliability, and lack of satisfaction in sex and sensual pleasures, you'll gradually lose interest in that.
Just as most people understand how being addicted to heroin and alcohol is a losing proposition.
Once you can file away porn and sexual activity in that same category, you'll not be attracted to it the way most people can be trained not to be attracted to heroin.

Answer (score 0):

Watching and making porn is a distraction, it cultivates lobha drenched, greed-based mind states. Watching porn goes against the wholesome Dharma. It is sensual. It's the cultivation of sense pleasure and bodily juices instead of allowing the cultivation of warm wholesome joy. Foul body contemplation helps attachment to sex.

Answer (score -1):

As I see, there are few downsides.

1)
According to Buddhism, thought is the primary actor. So, virtually it's equal to having actual sex.(in your mind) Though it's not intensive as actual sex. (virtual sex is less intensive, less harmful)

2)
Virtually or actually, when you do sex it leads to more sex. (virtually or actually)(a growth)

3)
It reduces purity of the mind.

4)
It adds up bad karma.

I actually don't recommend stopping it, unless you are seriously going for Nirvana. That's because, if you stop it without strengthening your mind enough, your mind and body will start to act differently / can be harmful on your social life.

Comment: I feel like it's at least healthier than having multiple casual partners and ending up catching an STD etc or becoming attached to someone who doesn't feel the same way.  It's kind of common knowledge that in some religions etc where they are celibate that their sexuality comes out in really unhealthy ways. Look at the Catholic church for example

Comment: Yes. But unless you are really considering reach Nirvana/or focus on meditation in this life, I would say to get married. That's because, unless, you would feel lost hope, purpose less. That's bad. One should always have a purpose until the moment they reach Nirvana. Otherwise they will think about things like suicide and stuff. Which Buddhism doesn't approve as good.

Answer (score -3):

If porn is not harmful, why would it be harmful to children?

Porn is degenerate, addictive, ignorant and contrary to the Buddhist way of life.

Also, sexual urges are mental rather than biological.